# Can someone clarify what for example the <> mean in the context of creating a instance of object/array

Tags: typescript

I'm new to programming and I've tried to find an answer to this online without success.

The question is probably stupid but when you create an instance of an object or an array you see that people use the `<string>` or `<className>` `<boolean>` etc.

1. I realise it means that what will be placed in the list, array or whatever but why should I?
2. is it more efficient if I declare what will be in it?
3. is it cause its a part of the (randomClassName) which implements an interface requiring it?

**If there is some name for the operator/practice you can just tell me the name and I can educate myself and hopefully won't waste your time:)**

Since I can't find any info online why it's used I feel like I'm just stupid and miss something.

Comment: A starting point for "why": you can try googling "benefits of static typing", should be bunches of articles on the subject (though only some reasons will be relevant to your particular JS setup)

Comment: It's called a generic type argument. See here https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html

Comment: Thx for the quick and helpful response, i will read up on it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this question has a fair bit of history.

Many languages have an equivalent of a mixed array. If we use one of these, we have to handle the additional possibilities that exist because each element can be different...

```
function processArray(mixedArray: Array<any>) {
    for (const element of mixedArray) {
        if (typeof element === 'number') {
            console.log('The number is', element);
        } else {
            console.log('This function only accepts numbers');
        }
    }
}

processArray([1, true, 'string']);
```

You will need to perform checks against the type every time you access them, and handle cases where there type isn't supported. Before long, your whole application is littered with these checks (or latent errors because the checks are missing).

This is basically where types come in, because they allow the compiler to perform checks for this class of error without the need for all of that code litter.

```
function processArray(numberArray: Array<number>) {
    for (const element of numberArray) {
        console.log('The number is', element);
    }
}

// The compiler now handles the problems here...
// 'true' is not a number
// 'string' is not a number
processArray([1, true, 'string']);
```

So, you *can* use mixed arrays if you want to - but it is better if you can signal what types are needed rather than write code to handle it yourself.

In cases such as...

```
const data: Array<string> = [];
```

The part within the `<>` is a type argument. You can find out more about this by researching generics.